# i am currently following angela yu coure of web dev.passport _local-mongoose error.even chatgpt uggest me to use bcrypt instead

Tags: authentication, backend, passport-local-mongoose

error : connected to db

server is connected to 3000 port

{ username: 'co.a.54.tanvirkamble@gmail.com', password: 'uiop' }

ctor [MissingUsernameError]: No username was given

```
at C:\Users\TANVIR\OneDrive\Desktop\web devlopment\Secrets - Starting Code\node_modules\passport-local-mongoose\index.js:231:17

at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)
```

[check the code here with this commit msg '
adding passport authentication but with error in output'](https://github.com/tanvirkamble/authentication-secrets)

Comment: Please read [ask]. I cannot parse your post to find what your question is.